# RSPEC - Restore database from file on load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec

I have a rails project running rspec for tests and I'd like to restore the test DB from a dump file each time RSPEC is initiated. I tried writing some config in the `rails_helper` file under the rspec block, but it was unable to restore the DB with system commands due to the DB being in use.

How am I able to restore the DB from a dump file when rspec is loaded?

Using Rails 5 and psql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by doing the following in the `rails_helper` under the RSpec configure block:

```
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  system('bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=test')
  system('rake db:drop')
  system('rake db:create')
  system('pg_restore --no-acl --no-owner -d name_of_databse test.dump')
  ActiveRecord::Base::establish_connection
```